# Angular routing with slash followed by hash

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 8 project. I have a route that matches to a path, let's say 'cake'. My problem is when I try to access cake/#/chocolate it automatically changes the URL into cake#/chocolate.

I have noticed that if I disable the initialNavigation from the ExtraOptions of the router module the URL stays as cake/#/chocolate but then the routing doesn't take place.

Can someone let me know how I can disabled the deletion of the first slash after 'cake'?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the code . How you allow the hash strategy ?

Comment: Why do you want to have the first slash after the cake? Because the routing will work fine anyways

Comment: Hi. That's the thing I don't want to allow the hash strategy. Background: we have a domain a.com where an Angular 8 application lives and another domain b.com where an Angular JS application lives. We want to move the Angular 8 application from a.com to b.com and for this to work without changing some URL in the e-mails (initially) we want to write some redirects. Of course the Angular JS application has hash enabled (a/#/page) but the Angular 8 application doesn't. 

I have managed to write the redirect module but still I want to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

1. First Import this on `app.module.ts`

   ```
   import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
   ```
2. And use in provider like this

   ```
   providers: [
       {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
   ],
   ```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution solves something completely different that what I actually need.